# Identifying Source of Android Crash - Java Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, google-play-console

My app is in production in the Play Store and this is my biggest source of crashes. For months I haven't been able to identify the source, my app uses numerous arrays and I've combed through them but no change I have made  has been the solution. The Google Play Console provides me this reasoning:

```
Type: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 90 out of bounds for length 0
  at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds (Preconditions.java:64)
  at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex (Preconditions.java:70)
  at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex (Preconditions.java:266)
  at java.util.Objects.checkIndex (Objects.java:359)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:434)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

But, as far as I can tell, this does give me much to go off. I cannot tell which class this error may be in, or which method, or line and so forth. So I have no clue where to look.

However, I may be ignorant of how to read these clues. Do the numbers mean anything to my code? For example Thread.java 1012 or ArrayList.java:434? I could fix this so easily if I knew where to look. Any assistance would be appreciated.

PS - I've implemented try/catch in numerous spots within the code where I thought there might be an issue, but that has not worked.